# hide_row() in pysimplegui work only one time?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I use hide_row() element or feature in my code to hide row but it work only one time when i connected to Retreat button or Retreat key, when i clicked again or in the 2nd time it's not work (see the code or try it to understand what i mean) how make it work continuously not only one time or is there another way to undo or delete section or row.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [

[sg.Col([[sg.T('Enter your name:'),sg.In()],[sg.Btn('Ok'), sg.Btn('Exit'),
sg.Btn('Add new row')]],k='col_key')]

]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ('Exit' ,sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break

    if event == ('Add new row'):
        window.extend_layout(window['col_key'],[[sg.T('Enter your name:', key='new_raw'),(sg.In())]])
        window.extend_layout(window['col_key'],[[sg.Btn('Retreat', key='re')]])

    if event == ('re'):
        window['new_raw'].hide_row()
        window['re'].hide_row()

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by new element with duplicate key when add new row again, so it wll always find the first element when you call `window[new_key]`.

Should use different key for different element when you create a new element.

Key of new element will be replace by

```py
element.Key = str(element.Key) + str(self.UniqueKeyCounter)
```

So key for new elements will be

```py
'new_raw', 're', 'new_raw0', 're1', 'new_raw2', 're3',  'new_raw4', 're5', ...
```

you can check it by

```py
>>> window.key_dict
{
...
 'new_raw': <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object at 0x000001D3A5B80FA0>,
 'new_raw0': <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object at 0x000001D3A6FA1280>,
 'new_raw2': <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object at 0x000001D3A6FA1220>,
 're': <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Button object at 0x000001D3A6FA1CD0>,
 're1': <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Button object at 0x000001D3A6FA1340>,
 're3': <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Button object at 0x000001D3A6FA11F0>}
```

After new row generated, the key of button `Retreat` is not 're', but starts with 're' and ends with an index.

Update code as following

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [

[sg.Col([[sg.T('Enter your name:'),sg.In()],[sg.Btn('Ok'), sg.Btn('Exit'),
sg.Btn('Add new row')]],k='col_key')]

]

window = sg.Window('Test', layout)
index = 0
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in ('Exit' ,sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break

    if event == ('Add new row'):
        window.extend_layout(window['col_key'],[[sg.T('Enter your name:', key=f'new_raw {index}'),(sg.In(key=f'input {index}'))]])
        window.extend_layout(window['col_key'],[[sg.Btn('Retreat', key=f're {index}')]])
        index += 1

    if event.startswith('re'):
        i = event.split(' ')[-1]
        window[f'new_raw {i}'].hide_row()
        window[f're {i}'].hide_row()

window.close()
```

There's still problem for old rows hidden will still be kept in memory, so occupied memory will grow higher and higher if you add new row again and again, but it's not question to be discussed here.

Comment: First, thanks for answering my question
Secondly, I think you did not understand my question or I did not understand your answer correctly, Can you please explain your answer to the code that i put its easy to me if i saw your answer or solution in my code , and also if i understand your answer as i understood its not solve my problem in my code its still same problem i give new key for every element still same problem.
Thanks.

Comment: update as above.